# How to get random Id at cloud firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I was using realtime database in my android app. Now I started using cloud firestore. in firebase real time database I was using this code :

```
    final String postId = postsReference.push().getKey();
    final DatabaseReference currentPostRef = postsReference.child(postId);

    currentPostRef.setValue(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            //TO ensure that the child exists
            if (currentPostRef.child("posted") != null) {
                currentPostRef.child("posted").setValue(true);
                currentPostRef.child("date").setValue(date);

                for (int i = 0; i < postsList.size(); i++) {
                    if (postsList.get(i).getId().equals(postId)) {
                        postsList.get(i).setPosted(true);
                        postsList.get(i).setDate(date);
                        view.notifyAdapter();
                        break;
                    }
                }
    });
```

I tried to use add method but I couldn't get the id .I need to get the id and store it in a variable before using it as the example above how can I do that in cloud firestore.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to get the ID of an object that is already in the database, or do you want to generate a random ID to use in the database?

Comment: @grooveplex I need to get new random id to use it

Comment: IIRC, Firebase (or at least the client libraries) take care of that for you.

Comment: I need to know the random id generated when added to use it

Comment: You get back a `DocumentReference`, which contains a `getId()` method: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference

Comment: @grooveplex can you please explain more how to do that

Comment: The Firestore equivalent of `push()` with no arguments is [`doc()`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.17.x/CollectionReference#doc) with no arguments.  It will return a DocumentReference object which has a getId() method, as Frank said.